# Use Scrapy and Selenium to scrape pages that require login and use javascript to load data

Tags: javascript, authentication, selenium, scrapy

I am trying to scrape pages that require login and load data using javascript. Currently I can log in successfully using scrapy. But my spider cannot see the data I need because the data is loaded using javascript.

I did some search and found Selenium could be a possible solution. I want to use selenium to create a browser and see the page. It seems that I should use selenium webdriver tool. But I don't know how to do that. Does anyone know where and how I should add selenium codes to my spider?

Many thanks.

```
#My spider looks like

from scrapy.spider import BaseSpider
from scrapy.selector import HtmlXPathSelector
from scrapy.http import Request, FormRequest

from scrapy.contrib.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
from scrapy.contrib.linkextractors.sgml import SgmlLinkExtractor

from selenium import selenium
import time

from login.items import SummaryItem

class titleSpider(BaseSpider):
    name = "titleSpider"
    allowed_domains = ["domain.com"]
    start_urls = ["https://www.domain.com/login"]

    # Authentication
    def parse(self, response):
        return [FormRequest.from_response(response,
                formdata={'session_key': 'myusername', 'session_password': 'mypassword'},
                callback=self.after_login)]

    # Request the webpage
    def after_login(self, response):
        # check login succeed before going on
        if "Error" in response.body:
            print "Login failed"
        else:
            print "Login successfully"
            return Request(url="https://www.domain.com/result1",
               callback=self.parse_page) # this page has some data loaded using javascript


    def __init__(self):
        CrawlSpider.__init__(self)
        self.verificationErrors = []
        # How can I know selenium passes authentication? 
        self.selenium = selenium("localhost", 4444, "*firefox", "https://www.domain.com/result1")
        print "Starting the Selenium Server!"
        self.selenium.start()
        print "Successfully, Started the Selenium Server!"

    def __del__(self):
        self.selenium.stop()
        print self.verificationErrors
        CrawlSpider.__del__(self)

    # Parse the page
    def parse_page(self, response):

        item = SummaryItem()
        hxs = HtmlXPathSelector(response)
        item['name']=hxs.select('//span[@class="name"]/text()').extract() # my spider cannot see the name.

        # Should I add selenium codes here? Can it load the page that requires authentication?
        sel= self.selenium
        sel.open(response.url)
        time.sleep(4)
        item['name']=sel.select('//span[@class="name"]/text()').extract() # 

        return item
```

Comment: I found a workaround. I use Selenium webdrive to log in the website and parse webpages. It works well!

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this

```
def __init__(self):
    BaseSpider.__init__(self)
    self.selenium = webdriver.Firefox()

def __del__(self):
    self.selenium.quit()
    print self.verificationErrors

def parse(self, response):

    # Initialize the webdriver, get login page
    sel = self.selenium
    sel.get(response.url)
    sleep(3)
```